# How do I drop one of the inputs on this for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am doing an assignment where I need to calculate an average grade, in one part I have a for loop where it takes the input of 5 quiz grades, I can't figure how to drop the lowest grade out of the ones entered during calculation.

```
print("Please enter 5 quiz grades.")
print("\t")
for i in range(5):
    quizgrade = float(input("Quiz grade: "))
    quizgradetotal += quizgrade
print("\t")
```

here is the code so far.

I have tried changing the loop, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: your problem is that you're not storing individual grades. Store the inputs in a list of floats, and do calculations outside the input loop...

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can approach this is to store each entered quiz grade in a list. Then you can drop the lowest grade once you know all of the grades:

```
quizgrades = [] # Initialize an empty list
print("Please enter 5 quiz grades.")
print("\t")

# Grab all 5 quiz grades
for i in range(5):
    quizgrades.append(float(input("Quiz grade: ")))

# Now remove the lowest number from the list
quizgrades.remove(min(quizgrades))

# Now that you have a list with the lowest grade dropped, you can easily calculate the average

average = sum(quizgrades) / len(quizgrades)
 
print(average)
```

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to store all your inputs in one array

```
gards = [] 
for i in range(5):
    gards.append(float(input("Quiz grade: ")))
```

then remove the lowest grade :

```
gards.remove(min(gards))
```

finally you calculate the average of the array :

```
average = sum(gards) / 4
```

your solution is good you can overwrite the sum on every input by adding the new value then calculate the average. but the problem is that you will never know which one is the lowest once the loop is over.

Comment: An improvement to this would be if the average is calculated with the length of the list and not with 5, right? Otherwise, you get funny results. As is in the answer of @John Ingram below

Comment: since `for i in range(5)` the array length will always be `5`

Comment: But you do remove the `min` right? after that length should be `4`.

Comment: yes you are right missed this one ^^' thank you